# 'IO_START' undeclared error appears when compiling the 4.4.3 goldfish android kernel

Tags: android, linker, linux-kernel

something i should mention that i add fuse support to the kernel,and it prompt such error duing make:
   CC      drivers/char/goldfish_tty.o
    drivers/char/goldfish_tty.c: In function 'goldfish_tty_probe':
    drivers/char/goldfish_tty.c:233: error: 'IO_START' undeclared (first use in this function)
    drivers/char/goldfish_tty.c:233: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    drivers/char/goldfish_tty.c:233: error: for each function it appears in.)
    make[2]: *** [drivers/char/goldfish_tty.o] Error 1
    make[1]:**  [drivers/char] Error 2
    make: ** [drivers] Error 2

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?  If so, please post it here.

Comment: it is caused by the setting of the make.u must use the correct setting,